# Non-breaking switch statements

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, break

I understand that in MATLAB it is not necessary (as it is in C++) to end each 'case' of a switch statement with a 'break;'. The statement stops evaluating once it finds the first successful case.

However, I have the following situation:

```
switch variable
    case {0, 1}
        % Action A
    case {0, 2}
        % Action B
end
```

In the above situation, if 'variable' equals 0, then only Action A will complete. In the case of variable = 0, I'd like *both* actions to complete. I *could* make a separate case for 0 which activates both Actions A & B, but that hardly seems like efficient programming as I'd have to duplicate both the actions.

I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this, but I'm still a relative newbie to MATLAB so I wonder what I could do to keep my code tidy?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code length is not necessarily the same as readability or efficiency.  I would argue that the right answer is to discard the switch and just write what you mean:

```
if((variable == 0) || (variable == 1))
  ActionA();
end

if((variable == 0) || (variable == 2))
  ActionB();
end
```

Answer (score 7):

The MATLAB [`switch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/switch.html) statement unfortunately does not provide the flexibility of fall-through logic, so you won't be able to use it in this case.

You could replace the `switch` with successive `if` statements (accompanied by a few comments) and this is what you'd get:

```
%# Switch variable
if (variable == 0 || variable == 1)  %# case {0, 1}
   %# Action A
end
if (variable == 0 || variable == 2)  %# case {0, 2}
   %# Action B
end
```

and it would still look elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You state

> I could make a separate case for 0 which activates both Actions A & B, but that hardly seems like efficient programming as I'd have to duplicate both the actions.

Regardless of efficiency, this is probably the most readable thing to do. I would always go for readability until you can prove that some piece of code is a bottleneck. So I would write:

```
switch variable
    case 0
        ActionA()
        ActionB()
    case 1
        ActionA()
    case 2
        ActionB()
end

function ActionA()
    ...
end

function ActionB()
    ...
end
```

If you really want a non-breaking switch you can follow the advice from a MATLAB Central [blog post on the switch statement](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/04/28/switching-things-up/):

> To achieve fall-through behavior in MATLAB, you can specify all the relevant expressions in one case and then conditionally compute values within that section of code.